# How to read value from website

Tags: android, json, jsoup

I just want to read (-1) value which is the only value in website but I am not able to fetch this value Can any buddy guide me how to do that. I am getting the value of API url when I am pasting it in web browser and android is not fetching it. Link of API is given below.

[Link OF API](https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/411172/feeds.json?results=2)

Code I am trying is:

```
    private void getWebsite() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/411172/feeds.json?results=1").get();
                String title = doc.title();
                Elements links = doc.select("[pre]");

                builder.append(title).append("\n");

                for (Element link : links) {
                    builder.append("\n").append("Link : ").append(link.attr("pre"))
                            .append("\n").append("Text : ").append(link.text());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**Screen shot of web API call in browser**
[image: Here is the picture of Web API call]
Error I am getting is **Error: HTTP error fetching URL**

Comment: api.thingspeak.com actually returns `-1` ...you might be missing an active login.

Comment: Please set an Active URL those give a response this is not gives any response so you got a -1 error.

Comment: yes I want to take alternative Because when ever I entered different Channel id which is not public my application got close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see response from your API is JSON formatted you have to modify your code as follow

```
private void getWebsite() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/411172/feeds.json?results=1")
                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                        .get();
                String json = doc.body().text();
                builder.append(json);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Not Working for me :)

Comment: You API response is updated now. So i have updated my answer too. Please try again now with updated code.

Comment: Are You there i need help

Comment: How can I help you?

Comment: How can I do chat with you?

Comment: I see no option available here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178150/discussion-between-k132133-syed-arsalan-hussain-and-anisuzzaman-babla).